# mysql long time query excute

Tags: mysql, buffer, innodb, myisam

i have many myisam tables and one innodb table, and many queries from these tables.
connection to database is every second from multiple computers to check if these computers have update or not.

2 days ago i changed some other tables to INNODB, then i faced the below high time execution for the original table INNODB (wasn't like this before). so today i returned them back to MyISAM and kept the INNODB table as it was.

MySQL-Processes sample (shows only the INNODB table that were worked fine before):

time: 100
state: Updating
info:

```
UPDATE terminal_update SET `update_flag`=1 , `update_date`= '2013-12-27 19:29:17' , `download_date`= '2013-12-27 15:28:51' WHERE com_id = '14852' and update_id = '71'
```

Querycache Status:

```
Qcache_free_blocks      1

Qcache_free_memory      90171104

Qcache_hits             15853 

Qcache_inserts          7600 

Qcache_lowmem_prunes    0 

Qcache_not_cached       4607 

Qcache_queries_in_cache 4298 

Qcache_total_blocks     8775
```

what should i do?

Comment: check if there has index on  `com_id` and `update_id` column

Comment: ok i did for update_id, com_id was already indexed, thanks a lot